# Cannot invoke "javax.script.ScriptEngine.eval(String)" because "this.engine" is null

Tags: java

Buen día con todos, necesito un poco de ayuda es esta pequeña practica que estaba realizando
Si alguien talvez sabe el porque de este error y me pudiera ayuda, si talvez tienen alguna recomendación sobre el código, bienvenida sea.

Resalto que ya le intente con "js". Si talvez alguien tiene alguna idea y me podría ayudar.

errores :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: 
Cannot invoke "javax.script.ScriptEngine.eval(String)" because "this.engine" is null
 > at gui.Main.lambda$new$25(Main.java:113)
        resultadoField.setText(engine.eval(obtenerProblema(text)).toString());
 > at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased
```

El código se trata de trabajar con interfaces graficas, por lo que:

```
package gui;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.lang.String;
import java.lang.Math;
```

Omitiré cosas para acortar el código

```
public class Main {
    //Aqui van los paneles, botones, labes,etc
    private ScriptEngine engine;
    private void createUIComponents() {
    problemaField = new JTextField();
    resultadoField = new JTextField();
    }
    public  Main() {
        ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript"); // JavaScript engine
        btn0.addActionListener(e -> problemaField.setText(problemaField.getText() + 0));
        //Asi hasta el 9 y un char '.'
        btnSumar.addActionListener(e -> problemaField.setText(problemaField.getText() + '+'));
        //De igual manera con el resto de signos y símbolos, incluyendo las funciones trigonométricas de esta manera "tan(",etc. Funcionan sin problema
        //Luego tengo mas botones que están correctos excepto este, el cual es quien arroja el error
        btnEqual.addActionListener(e -> {
        String text = problemaField.getText();
        obtenerProblema(text);
        try {
            resultadoField.setText(engine.eval(obtenerProblema(text)).toString()); //<- aquí me arroja el error
        } catch (ScriptException scriptException) {
            scriptException.printStackTrace();
          }
        });
    }
    public String obtenerProblema(String problemaField) {
        // Reemplazar los símbolos y funciones matemáticas
        problemaField = problemaField
                .replace("sin", "Math.sin")
                .replace("cos", "Math.cos")
                .replace("tan", "Math.tan")
                .replace("csc", "1/Math.sin")
                .replace("sec", "1/Math.cos")
                .replace("cot", "1/Math.tan")
                .replace("sqrt", "Math.sqrt")
                .replace("PI", "Math.PI")
                .replace("PI", Math.PI + "")
                .replace("^2", "**2") // Cambia **2 a *2 para la potencia
                .replace("%", "/100");

        System.out.println(problemaField);
        return problemaField;
    // Evaluate la expresión
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Calculadora");
        frame.setContentPane(new Main().panMain);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Muchas gracias de antemano a quien se tomo la molestia de leer este problema.

Comment: Hola, ese error se produce cuando un objeto de devuelve null. En tu caso, parece que el objeto engine es null cuando intentas llamar al método eval() en él. Si engine es null, eso significa que manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript") está devolviendo null

Comment: Hola. Prueba así: `engine = manager.getEngineByName("js");`  o así: `engine = manager.getEngineByExtension("js");` Si sigue sin funcionar, intenta agregar el siguiente módulo desde la consola: `java --add-modules jdk.scripting.nashorn`Supongo que tendrás las dependencias necesarias en tu proyecto.

Comment: que version de java tienes?

Comment: Tengo la versión de java 21